# Umbraco Tinymce adding spaces to empty tags

Tags: tinymce, umbraco, umbraco7, rich-text-editor, rte

Whenever I add some tags like `<i></i>` to use with awesome font or simply a `<p></p>` tag tinymce automatically adds a space in between the tags. I have searched around the internet but couldn't find any solution.

Another solution would be to remove the spaces with javascript but that is a solution I want to keep as a last resort.

Comment: Which version of Umbraco (&/or tinyMCE) are you using? You can change the way TinyMCE generates the tags by editing the config or js files for it. I know I have done this before, but now I cannot find how/where/info on what I did. Sorry I cannot give you the details but perhaps that will help in your search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently had the same problem and finally found a solution. In the tinyMceConfig.config on the bottom u find:

```
<validElements></validElements>
```

In there find the:

```
-em/-i[class|style]
```

element and change it to:

```
-em[class|style],i[class|id|style]
```

Then in your ClientDepency.config change your version with +1 so if it is 1 now change it to 2:

```
<clientDependency version="2" fileDependencyExtensions=".js,.css" loggerType="Umbraco.Web.UI.CdfLogger, umbraco">
```

Hope this helped!